# How to align flex items in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am trying create a Single Page Application which compares broadband deals and want to align align flex box items like this image. For some reason the items are not centered and not properly aligned the way I want it to. Btw this is a code snippet of my JSX code, so the main code is just a container which maps the items retrieved from an api.

[image]

But i keep getting this image

[image]

Here is my code

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
}

.companyName {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.companyInfo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  float: left;
}

.price {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 5px solid #1C6EA4;
}
```

```html
<div className='container'>
  {/**Company Name */}
  <div className='companyName'>
    <img src={deals.provider_logo_image_url} alt='logo' style={{ width: '4%' }}></img>
    <div className='companyInfo'>
      <div>{deals.provider_name}</div>
      <div>{deals.deal_name}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {/**Monthly Price */}
  <div className='price'>
    <div>Monthly Cost</div>
  </div>
  {/**Setups Price */}
  <div className='price'>
    <div>Setups Price</div>
  </div>
  {/**Remove to compare */}
  <div className='price'>
    <div>Remove to compare</div>
  </div>
  {/**Continue */}
  <div className='price'>
    <div>Continue</div>
  </div>
  {/**More */}
  <div className='price'>
    <div>More</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've made a snippet out of your code, but you really should use HTML comments in HTML code. These weird `{/**  */}` are screwing up the result (I guess it's unprocessed React code)

Comment: This is one of those few cases where using table actually makes sense, since you’re presenting tabulated data.

Comment: @Terry They can also use [Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: @mmiah could you please share a reproduced demo on stackblitz?

Comment: @JeremyThille this is JSX code so the {/** */} is a comment

Comment: Why grid when table is already the semantically correct element to use?

Comment: Highly recommend, if your items are laid out as a grid, to use css grid formatting and forget using flex for this. If you have to use flex, give each child in the row `flex-basis: 0` and `flex-grow: 1` and each will take the same width.

Comment: I know it's JSX comments, but Stackoverflow's snippets don't support JSX out of the box. It would be better to provide final, processed HTML

Answer (score 0):

first things first you need to warp your price divs in another div so that they're grouped together.Try something like this...

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
}

.companyName {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 300px;
}

.companyInfo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  float: left;
}

.prices{
  flex-grow: 1;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.price {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 5px solid #1C6EA4;
 
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='companyName'>
    <img src="test" alt='logo'></img>
    <div class='companyInfo'>
      <div>Provider Name</div>
      <div>Deal Name</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prices">
    <div class='price'>
      <div>Monthly Cost</div>
    </div>
    <div class='price'>
      <div>Setups Price</div>
    </div>
    <div class='price'>
      <div>Remove to compare</div>
    </div>
    <div class='price'>
      <div>Continue</div>
    </div>
    <div class='price'>
      <div>More</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='companyName'>
    <img src="test" alt='logo'></img>
    <div class='companyInfo'>
      <div>Provider Name</div>
      <div>Deal Name</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prices">
    <div class='price'>
      <div>Monthly Cost</div>
    </div>
    <div class='price'>
      <div>Setups Price</div>
    </div>
    <div class='price'>
      <div>Remove to compare</div>
    </div>
    <div class='price'>
      <div>Continue</div>
    </div>
    <div class='price'>
      <div>More</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've made your suggested changes and it seems to have aligned the boxes evenly but they are all still to the right?